# Font Awesome Unknown on Mac OS - Can't install

Tags: macos, fonts

I try to install Font-Awesome on my computer to make my design in photoshop. But I can't install it. When I try with Font Agent, the application show me: Unknown. 
And when I force the installation in the system, my computer make a warning and say: the document are corrupt.

I try to download the older version, but it not work too.

I'm on a MAC OS 10.10.5 (and the version of my Font Agent is 4.140)

Thank for help! :)
Martine

Answer (score 0):

- download the font files from http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ (download on the right side)
- unzip the archive
- you’ll get 6 font files
- install the the file with the .otf extension (I don’t know Font Agent but with double click on the file it will work)
- open a textarea in photoshop and chose the font in your font list.
- choose individual symbol via copy paste or over `Type > Panels > Glyphs` (https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/glyph-panel.html)

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't work :( 
The Glyph Panels doesn't exist. 
When I select the textarea in photoshop and chose FontAwesome, I have a * juste at the end of the name.

(Sorry, my english is not very good)

Comment: did you try to install the font with Apple Font Book (Applications › Font Book.app, depends on the os language)? Sometimes you need to restart Photoshop.